# I need to be sure that these are right values for MOSFET 2N7000

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, proteus, test

I made A circuit for test mosfet in proteus But according to datashet the values are incorrects. I need your help : Is it normal these values ?

[image: proteus]

For example : V(gs) in my circuit is 4 volts and amperage is 0.40 amps. But in datasheet for v(gs)=4 volts amperage is from 0.5 to 0.75 amps. look:

[image: datasheet]

So whats the problem. Best regards.

Comment: "Typical" datasheet values are recipriversexclusons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fairchild datasheet for the [2N7000](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N7000.pdf) shows different transfer characteristics which are closer to your results. It is important to realize that the graphs given in datasheets are typical values only. Your own part may vary widely from these.

[image]

If you look at the specs for the On-State Drain current you can see that at Vgs 4.5V it can be as low as 75mA, typically 600mA, and the maximum is not specified.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the current to any precision you need some kind of feedback. Probably the simplest is to add a series resistor that will have voltage drop of 0.6V at desired current. Add a NPN transistor base and emitter across it and the collector to the Mosfet Gate.

This will keep the current stable to a reasonable degree, subject to variations in the transistor base voltage of course.

A more sophisticated and accurate method calls for an opamp feedback.